# Generating a MySQL hourly breakdown from current timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, time, timestamp

I'm afraid this is probably a very embarrassingly easy question - but my mind is just completely stuck at this hour.

I have a table that stores the number of activities carried out by different people, and the time it took place in.

I want to create a report that accepts the person's name as a parameter, and show the number of activities per hour for that person during each of the previous 24 hours starting from current timestamp (`now()`).

Right now,

```
SELECT hour(TimeStamp), activities FROM tbl1 
WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  AND Name = ? 
GROUP BY hour(timestamp)
```

only returns to me those hours when any activity was present. However, I want a complete 24 hour breakdown with zero for when there was no activity.

i.e. I'm getting

```
Hour | No. of Activities
1    | 34
4    | 22
9    | 86
```

but I want

```
Hour | No. of Activities
1    | 34
2    | 0
3    | 0
4    | 22
5    | 0
... etc.
```

How do I do this?

(The order of hours in the example is irrelevant)

Comment: You should probably handle this in your app logic.

Comment: If the current time is, let's say, 5:30 do you want the first hour to be from 4:30 to 5:30 or 5 to 5:30?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `hourly` table, and do a `LEFT JOIN`

```
create table hourly
(
  /* hour is not a reserved keyword */
  hour smallint(2) not null default 0
);

insert into hourly values (0),(1).... until 24

SELECT 
  hourly.hour, 
  COALESCE(COUNT(activities),0) AS "No of Activities"
FROM hourly
LEFT JOIN tbl1 ON hourly.hour=hour(tbl1.TimeStamp)
WHERE 
  tbl1.timestamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND 
  tbl1.Name=? 
GROUP BY hourly.hour
ORDER BY hourly.hour;
```

Comment: @ajreal

Sorry, but I can't get the COALESCE function to return a Zero for some reason. 

`SELECT hourly.hour, COALESCE(activities, 0) FROM 
hourly LEFT JOIN tbl1 ON hourly.hour=hour(Timestamp)
WHERE timestamp  >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND Name = ? 
GROUP BY hour(timestamp)
ORDER BY hourly.hour
`
Still returns only the hours in which activities are present.

Comment: How about replace the GROUP BY to hourly.hour?

Comment: @ajreal

Tried both. Neither is working.

I must mention I am summing the activities, but trying without the sum doesn't work either. 

Am using MySQL 5.5.8

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Updated again, and next time please include more details. It does not work don't really helping...

Comment: @ajreal

I mean, I have grouped by hourly.hour as well. It still does not return me any rows for hours in which activity was not present. I have also tried IFNULL instead of COALESCE with similar results.

Comment: ,sorrymw brain is dead at te moment, you can try to join the hourly table with result of group by from your table .

Comment: which mean hourly left join (select group your table)

Comment: having another look, the current one should be correct.because is last 24 hour can check any row is matched ?

Comment: @ajreal

Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction this time.

Had to join it with the grouped query.

Comment: @ajreal

I've edited your answer. But it needs to be peer reviewed.

Comment: @colonel_px - I know it's been a while since this question was posted, but how did you get this to work? I'm having exactly the same issue, but the above solution isn't returning zero results.